# Silverstripe workflow $Context.AbsoluteEditLink not working

Tags: workflow, silverstripe

I have created a workflow by following this guide https://userhelp.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/optional_features/setting_up_advancedworkflow/setting-up-workflows/

However when I add $Context.AbsoluteEditLink to the notification email content field the url doesn't appear (nothing is shown) in the resulting email. I have checked elsewhere but cant find any answer.

Comment: https://github.com/symbiote/silverstripe-advancedworkflow/issues/240

Comment: Awesome thanks that's fixed it.